# How to detect whether the OS supports 16-bit exes in Python?

Tags: python, win64

This is essentially the same as asking how to detect that I am running under a 64-bit version of Windows.

`os.name` gives 'nt' under both win7 64 and winXP 32 (my two available test computers).
`sys.platform` gives 'win32' in both of those cases.

It looks like the only thing I've found so far that works is to check the registry key `HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0\Identifier` and if 'x86' doesn't appear in it, assume that means 64-bit windows. Is that reliable?

(the python process needs to run under python 2.7 32-bit)

Comment: I figured something out but StackOverflow won't let me post an answer :( http://pastebin.com/4bsm84Tg

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RAQXg0IdfI

Comment: Oh heck my answer WAS in there! Just way down in one of the lower-rated answers XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider checking the `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` key in `os.environ`, and seeing if it's set to `x86` or not.

Alternatively, you can use the [`platorm.architecture()`](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html) call, but point it at a *different* executable from the Python one (since you're required to run under 32bit Python).